TensorD extension pack for the Package-X
Does anyone have a copy of TensorD extension pack for the Package-X?
The Package-X is a Mathematica package for QFT calculations. Unfortunately, it is no longer developed and the official website (archived) has been taken down. However, version 2.1.1 is available here, as mentioned in another question. The TensorD extension is not available at this link (by the way, version 3 beta of Package-X is missing, too).
The extension pack was licensed under CC-BY-4.0.
